# larger OpenSource projects to learn from proper style and patterns

Tags: android

I have checked http://code.google.com/p/iosched/ and the code of few libraries which I used. Now my project grew and it has around 40 classes with fragments, activities, dialogs just in com.myapp.android.ui and I would like to see how other people organize that. That's why the question to suggest some well written open source projects to learn from with emphasis on directory structure.

Currently mine looks following:

```
com.myapp.android
com.myapp.android.adapter
com.myapp.android.browser
com.myapp.android.exception
com.myapp.android.misc
com.myapp.android.model
com.myapp.android.provider
com.myapp.android.ui
com.myapp.android.util
com.myapp.android.view
com.myapp.android.webview
```

I wonder weather I should organize files by blocks - like here where I have block called com.myapp.android.browser where I keep helper classes of BrowserActivity. Other Fragments/Activites are "smaller" so their helper classes are in com.myapp.android.util. Is it how people do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a particular right or wrong way, its whatever is best suited for you, or your team of developers needs.

I personally separate parts of the app out into modules. For example, all of the GUI control stuff is within the main default package. The logic part of the app, that actually does stuff based on what the user enters I usually put in a separate project, and if there is a particular section of the logic that could be quite big, or at least include several class files I separate this into a separate package, for example, my app performs background synchronisation so all of the classes related to the syncrhonisation are in a separate package.

As an example my app may contain the following packages.

**com.company.myapp**

This will contain all of the GUI control code, starting/ending of activities and user input. This bit would likely include data validation, i.e. are all the required edit text box filled in, if not, just show an error, if it is, pass to the logic function

**com.company.myapp.logic**

This will contain the logic part, the stuff that actually does something. I.e. variables that user enters from the GUI would get passed into the relevant classes within this package to process the data and return a result back to the GUI, e.g. `success` or `something has gone`wrong.

**com.company.myapp.sync**

All of the code that is related to data synchronisation between multiple devices

Hope this helps